# Volume enclosed by Implicit Surface

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, volume

I am trying to calculate the Volume that's enlcosed by the surface:
$$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 = xyz$$
The following is what i tried. I rewrote it in spherical coordinates where $x=r \cdot \sin\vartheta \cdot \cos\varphi$, $y=r\cdot\sin\vartheta\cdot\sin\varphi$, $z=r\cdot\cos\vartheta$ and could solve for $r$:
$$r=\sin ^2\vartheta\cdot\cos\vartheta\cdot\sin\varphi\cdot\cos\varphi$$
With this $r$ i could parametrize my $z$ giving me
$$z(\vartheta,\varphi)=\sin^2\vartheta\cos^2\vartheta\cos\varphi\sin\varphi$$
The volume of a solid can be calculated with a Surface Integral so $\iint_S z \ dx \ dy $ should give me what i want.
The Functional Determninant of going from cartesian to spherical is:
$$\frac{D(x,y)}{D(\vartheta,\varphi)}=\begin{vmatrix}x_\vartheta & x_\varphi\\y_\vartheta & y_\varphi\end{vmatrix}=r^2\cdot\cos\vartheta\cdot\sin\vartheta$$
So my Integral would look like
$$V=\int_{\varphi=o}^{2\pi}\int_{\vartheta=0}^\pi \sin^7\vartheta\cos^5\vartheta \ \cos^3\varphi\sin^3\varphi \ d\vartheta \ d\varphi$$
Where did i go wrong?

Comment: It would be easier to do the volume integral in spherical coordinates. You already figured out the $r$-limits for that integral.

Comment: You should only compute the integral for those $(\theta,\phi)$ where $xyz > 0$. Using symmetry, that is equivalent to compute the integral over $[0,\pi/2]^2$ and then multiply the result by $4$.

Comment: Note that the surface will flip to the opposite octant when $r<0$.  And $(\theta,\phi) \in [0,\pi] \times [0,\pi]$ or $(\theta,\phi) \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \times [0,2\pi]$ is enough to generate the whole surface.